# What is this strange flash drive icon in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, icons

I connected a USB flash drive to my laptop and it is displayed with this strange icon in the Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer Flash Drive Icon: Devices with red backgrounds and a white letter L]

It's certainly not the default icon and I didn't change any icon settings in windows. Its not stored on the flash drive itself, other flash drives have the same icon. I've used Google reverse image search and found a few screenshots that show the same icon but no hints where it comes from.

What is this icon or how can I check which application causes this icon to appear?

*Edit:* It's a Lenovo laptop and the L on the red background looks suspiciously like the Lenovo logo, so it's probably from some preinstalled software. I would still like to know how and why this icon is shown.

Comment: When Windows 8 was released.  Microsoft added a feature to allow users to select the device icon and/or image they wanted to use.  The fact "other drives have the same icon" indicate you accidentally made a change to which icon you wanted for removable drives.

Comment: @Ramhound Changing the icon for a particular drive is easy, but changing the default icon seems to require modifying the registry. I've looked up the entry in regedit but there are no default icons set up.